# Kotlin: Cannot find existing text file

Tags: android, kotlin

I got a file

```
val testFile = File(filesDir, "test.txt")
```

which returns true when I check for existance.

```
testFile.exists()
```

When I print filesDir,

```
println("FilesDir = " + filesDir)
```

I get following output: FilesDir = /data/user/0/com.example.myfirstapp/files

So the testFile should be stored there. 
Unfortunately, there is no folder called "data" in my internal phone storage. The only folder that is likely is "/Android/data" but there is no folder named "user" (and also no folder named "com.example.myfirstapp").
I also looked for a occurence of "myfirstapp" with phone search + search of my computer and could not find anything.

My question: **Where is "test.txt" file stored or why can't I find it although the "exists()" method returns true?**

Comment: `data` is a system folder in the internal storage. You need root access to manipulate it. TotalCommander will let you navigate to it (great app).

Comment: You can't access the data folder without a rooted device. They are only visible by the application that created it

Comment: Did you connect your device via USB to the debugger? You could find the directory using the device explorer in Android Studio